# Wait for page load before continuing JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to get this Tampermonkey script working. The scripts works just fine when it collects data from one page. However, I now want it to collect the data as before, but then move on to another page and continue the data collecting.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getData").click(function() {
        // Part 1. Collect data and move on
        window.location.href = goToURL;
        // Part 2. Collect more data when the page has fully loaded
    });
});
```

I have tired to put Part 2 of the code inside:

```
setTimeout(function() {
}, 5000);
```

and

```
window.onload = function(){
};
```

But I cannot get the code to work, it either executes before the page has loaded, or seemingly not at all. What am I missing?

Comment: New page means new instance of the code. Anything stored in memory is lost. Is new page on same domain?

Comment: Even when executing the code via Tampermonkey? 
Yes, it's on the same domain.

Comment: Yes...Tampermonkey runs new instance every page load. @Vladimir suggestion of localStorage is simple way to do it. Or use a cloud storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change page with `location.href`, your JS is reloaded. So you need a way to store data between page changing. I suggest to use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
Your code would look like:

```
function storeState(state){
    localStorage.setItem('state', state);
}

function loadState(state){
    return localStorage.getItem('state');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var state = getState();
    $("#getData").click(function() {
        // Collect data and put it into state
        storeState(/* your collected state*/)
        window.location.href = goToURL;
    });
});
```

Notice that you have to do some serialize/deserialize stuff because localStorage only save strings
Also as mentioned @charlietfl if you have different domains it will cause additional difficults

Comment: Should move comment for "Part 2" since won't be in the click handler